# Ruby: shortcuts for class instantiation

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to creat shortcuts for instantiation of custom classes in Ruby?

For example, for a subclass of Hash as below:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  # some custom methods
end
```

MyHash instances can be created like:

```
foo = MyHash[ :bar => 'baz' ]
```

or

```
foo = MyHash.new
foo[:bar] = 'baz'
```

That is fine enough, but I was wondering if there is a way to define a new shortcut like:

```
foo = my{ :bar => 'baz' }
```

Update:

As the goal might seem unclear, my main consideration here is to understand how ruby internally make the link between a shortcut like `{}` and `Hash.new`, and if it possible to create new shortcuts.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the shortcut you want to take.

Comment: I agree, but I am just curious to know it is possible.

Comment: There are parts of the Ruby syntax that can be overridden (e.g, `:+` and `:==`) and parts that can't.  I think `{}` falls into the second category.  But see Rubinius for a Ruby implementation that exposes more of the runtime to possible modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyHash < Hash; end

module Kernel
  def my h; MyHash[h] end
end
```

I think the best you can do is to use parentheses instead of braces, or surround the braces with parentheses.

```
foo = my(bar: "baz")
```

or

```
foo = my({bar: "baz"})
```

Though, I don't understand in what sense your expectation is a shortcut. I don't think `my{bar: "baz"}` (if possible) or `my(bar: "baz")` is any shorter than `MyHash[bar: "baz"]`

Comment: Neat! What I was meaning by shortcut is to understand how `{}` is interpreted as `Hash.new` or `[]`, `%w()`, `%W()` as `Array.new` and if it was possible to create custom ones. (It was more curiosity than any practical needs)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the fact that you can override the backtick operator, to get to a solution that is somewhat similar to what you requested. But I really would not advise to do anything like that :)

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def my_method
    # ...
  end
end

def `(hash)
  MyHash[eval(hash)]
end

foo = `{ :bar => "baz" }`
foo.respond_to? :my_method # => true
```

The syntax highlighting makes the code look broken, but it is not.

Comment: I sure would avoid this, but it is indeed an interesting trick! :)